# Google Sheet: How to prevent named range from being changed?

Tags: google-sheets

I make some named range on my Google sheet like

```
order_id: A2:A1000
```

New rows are added to this sheet via Zapier. After a while, I found the named range has become

```
order_id:A2:A1035
```

How to prevent this behavior and make the range stays A2:A1000?

Answer (score 1):

solution to this kind of depends on it's purpose and how you're using the named range downstream (in appScript?, just formulas?)

seems like the way to do this is to make the named range:

```
order_id: A2
```

then, in your code, use

```
sheet.getRange('order_id').offset(0,0,1000)
```

maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I have been checking the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) for Named ranges, it does not mention anything about that behavior.

I have been testing and I noticed the named range will expand when the rows are added within the range selected, not outside of it. I'd say the behavior is expected to avoid leaving data outside of the range accidentally.

If you are a Google Workspace customer you can try submitting a [Feature Idea](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762) since I do not see a way to leave the named range locked.